# Why does Scala gives input path not found error

Tags: scala, apache-spark, data-mining

I am newbie to scala and I'm trying to write a code which takes input from a file and does the word count process. I have mentioned the path of the input file, but during execution in command prompt, there's an error stating input path does not exist. There's an extra 'file' word attached in front of the path shown in the error.

Can anybody teach me how to fix this.
[Image of command prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ImPs.png)

This is my code:
[Wordcount code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LllqK.png)

Comment: Could you share how you load data to textRDD? Also the error is saying that `the file you are trying to load can't be found` so make sure it's there. And use `file:///your path` to load it.

Comment: I have added the picture of my code

Comment: I'd suggest that you look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fNlcyTGrPT8

Comment: Please include your code as text in the post itself

Answer (score 0):

> There's an extra 'file' word attached in front of the path shown in the error

`file:/` is a URI scheme that refers to your local filesystem. You're not reading from any Hadoop cluster.

You'll need to prove to us that your file does exist and Spark has permissions to read the E drive that's in the error